# RenderScript low performance on Samsung Galaxy S8

Tags: android, performance, animation, renderscript, samsung-s8

## Context

I have an Android app that takes a picture, **blurs** the picture, removes the blur **based on a mask** and applies a final layer (not relevant). The last 2 steps, removing the blur based on a mask and applying a final layer is done **repeatedly**, each time with a new mask (150 masks).

The output get's drawn on a canvas (SurfaceView). This way the app effectively creates a view of the image with an animated blur.

## Technical details & code

All of these image processing steps are achieved with **RenderScript**.

I'm leaving out the code for step 1, blurring the picture, since this is irrelevant for the problem I'm facing.

#### Step 2: removing the blur based on a mask

I have a **custom kernel** which takes an **in Allocation** as argument and holds **2 global variables, which are Allocations** as well.

These 3 Allocations all get their data from bitmaps using **Allocation.copyFrom(bitmap)**.

#### Step 3: applying a final layer

Here I have a **custom kernel** as well which takes an **in Allocation** as argument and holds **3 global variables**, of which 1 is and **Allocation** and 2 are **floats**.

How these kernels work is irrelevant to this question but just to be sure I included some simplified snippets below.

Another thing to note is that I am following all best practices to ensure performance is at its best regarding Allocations, RenderScript and my SurfaceView.

So common mistakes such as creating a new RenderScript instance each time, not re-using Allocations when possible,.. are safe to ignore.

*blurMask.rs*

```c
#pragma version(1)
#pragma rs java_package_name(com.example.rs)
#pragma rs_fp_relaxed

// Extra allocations
rs_allocation allocBlur;
rs_allocation allocBlurMask;

/*
 * RenderScript kernel that performs a masked blur manipulation.
 * Blur Pseudo: out = original * blurMask + blur * (1.0 - blurMask)
 * -> Execute this for all channels
 */
uchar4 __attribute__((kernel)) blur_mask(uchar4 inOriginal, uint32_t x, uint32_t y) {
    // Manually getting current element from the blur and mask allocations
    uchar4 inBlur = rsGetElementAt_uchar4(allocBlur, x, y);
    uchar4 inBlurMask = rsGetElementAt_uchar4(allocBlurMask, x, y);

   // normalize to 0.0 -> 1.0
    float4 inOriginalNorm = rsUnpackColor8888(inOriginal);
    float4 inBlurNorm = rsUnpackColor8888(inBlur);
    float4 inBlurMaskNorm = rsUnpackColor8888(inBlurMask);

    inBlurNorm.rgb = inBlurNorm.rgb * 0.7 + 0.3;

    float4 outNorm = inOriginalNorm;
    outNorm.rgb = inOriginalNorm.rgb * inBlurMaskNorm.rgb + inBlurNorm.rgb * (1.0 - inBlurMaskNorm.rgb);

    return rsPackColorTo8888(outNorm);
}
```

*myKernel.rs*

```c
#pragma version(1)
#pragma rs java_package_name(com.example.rs)
#pragma rs_fp_relaxed

// Extra allocations
rs_allocation allocExtra;

// Randoms; Values are set from kotlin, the values below just act as a min placeholder.
float randB = 0.1f;
float randW = 0.75f;

/*
 * RenderScript kernel that performs a manipulation.
 */
uchar4 __attribute__((kernel)) my_kernel(uchar4 inOriginal, uint32_t x, uint32_t y) {
    // Manually getting current element from the extra allocation
    uchar4 inExtra = rsGetElementAt_uchar4(allocExtra, x, y);

   // normalize to 0.0 -> 1.0
    float4 inOriginalNorm = rsUnpackColor8888(inOriginal);
    float4 inExtraNorm = rsUnpackColor8888(inExtra);

    float4 outNorm = inOriginalNorm;
    if (inExtraNorm.r > 0.0) {
        outNorm.rgb = inOriginalNorm.rgb * 0.7 + 0.3;
        // Separate channel operation since we are using inExtraNorm.r everywhere
        outNorm.r = outNorm.r * inExtraNorm.r + inOriginalNorm.r * (1.0 - inExtraNorm.r);
        outNorm.g = outNorm.g * inExtraNorm.r + inOriginalNorm.g * (1.0 - inExtraNorm.r);
        outNorm.b = outNorm.b * inExtraNorm.r + inOriginalNorm.b * (1.0 - inExtraNorm.r);
    }
    else if (inExtraNorm.g > 0.0) {
        ...
    }

    return rsPackColorTo8888(outNorm);
}
```

## Problem

So the app works great on a range of devices, even on low-end devices. I manually cap the FPS at 15, but when I remove this cap, I get results ranging from 15-20 on low-end devices to 35-40 on high-end devices.

The **Samsung Galaxy S8** is where my problem occurs. For some reason I only manage to get around 10 FPS. If I use **adb** to force RenderScript to use CPU instead:

```
adb shell setprop debug.rs.default-CPU-driver 1
```

I get around 12-15 FPS, but obviously I want it to run on the GPU.

#### An important, weird thing I noticed

If I trigger a touch event, no matter where (even out of the app), the performance dramatically increases to around 35-40 FPS. If I lift my finger from the screen again, FPS drops back to 10 FPS.

**NOTE: drawing the result on the SurfaceView can be excluded as an impacting factor since the results are the same with just the computation in RenderScript without drawing the actual result.**

## Questions

So I have more than one question really:

- What could be the reason behind the low performance?
- Why would a touch event improve this performance so dramatically?
- How could I solve or work around this issue?

Comment: Are the results the same when you build using `release` mode?